# Pyspark: cast element array with nested struct

Tags: python, pyspark

I have pyspark dataframe with a column named received: ""
how to access and convert the "size" element that is as a **string** into a **float** usando pyspark?

```
root                                                                            
 |-- title: string (nullable = true)
 |-- received: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- date: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- size: string (nullable = true)
 |-- urls: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- body: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- scheme: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- url: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ...
 |-- ...
```

I tried like this but I'm not getting success!

```
df.withColumn("received", SF.col("received").withField("delay", SF.col("received.delay").cast("float")))
```

Could someone guide me how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it like this:

```
df = df.withColumn(
      "received",
      SF.expr("""transform(
                  received, 
                  x -> struct(x.col1, x.col2, x.col3, x.col4, float(x.delay) as delay, x.col6))"""
      )
  )
```